# Does iOS storyboard have a feature equivalent to tools:text in android?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, localization, storyboard

I've just moved from android to iOS with swift.

android provides tools namespace that supports this kind of requirement. I just use tools:text="fake string" so that the string only appears on the IDE screen.

When it comes to iOS storyboard, while I'm drawing layout with storyboard, one question is remaining in my mind.
Can I have a fake string that only appears on the storyboard but not on iOS screen?

Please let me know if I can use the same feature in iOS programming.

Comment: hi @themuser.  as a new user, be sure to please tick or thumb the useful answers - so you get points and can ask more questions without moderation.  Re your question, apple's "localization" thing may help, and, you'll pretty much have to look in to that anyway.  get ready to spend a couple days learning about "autolayout" - which you can do trivially in android  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no fake text available. The text which you are setting in storyboard for a label will display while you are running the application. You can create reset/change this text in `viewDidLoad` of the corresponding view controller by creating an outlet of the label. Like

```
self.label.text = "New text"
```